# Develop in GNU Radio Companion; call top block's methods in separate Python file

Tags: python, gnuradio, gnuradio-companion

I would like to...

- Make a flowgraph in GNU Radio Companion
- Call methods from a separate Python file

For example, let's say I want to scan through center frequencies in this flowgraph:

```
Osmocom source --> NBFM Receive --> Audio sink
```

I'm guessing that [Message Passing](https://wiki.gnuradio.org/index.php/Message_Passing) would allow me to set the osmocom's center freq programmatically, but it would be easier (I think...?) to do something like this in Python:

```py
freqs = [100e6, 101e6]
for freq in freqs:
    set_center_freq(freq)
```

What do you suggest? (*I'm answering my own question, but I'm curious if others have suggested improvements!* )

Answer (score 0):

You can import the top block from the Python file generated by GRC. That way, when the file is regenerated, you don't lose your changes.

```py
from my_generated_FM_receiver import my_generated_FM_receiver

tb = my_generated_FM_receiver()
```

There's a little more setup to be done to run the flowgraph. (See [here](https://wiki.gnuradio.org/index.php/Flowgraph_Python_Code), lines 103-128, starting with `def main(top_block_cls...`).

If you want to access the `tb` variable, you can create a thread and pass `tb` as an argument, like so (this code is identical to the [usual generated code](https://wiki.gnuradio.org/index.php/Flowgraph_Python_Code) except for the two added lines near the end):

```py
from threading import Thread


def set_up_qt_top_block_and_run_func_in_thread(top_block_cls, func_to_run):

    if StrictVersion("4.5.0") <= StrictVersion(Qt.qVersion()) < StrictVersion("5.0.0"):
        style = gr.prefs().get_string('qtgui', 'style', 'raster')
        Qt.QApplication.setGraphicsSystem(style)
    qapp = Qt.QApplication(sys.argv)

    tb = top_block_cls()
    tb.start()
    tb.show()

    def sig_handler(sig=None, frame=None):
        Qt.QApplication.quit()

    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, sig_handler)
    signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, sig_handler)

    timer = Qt.QTimer()
    timer.start(500)
    timer.timeout.connect(lambda: None)

    def quitting():
        tb.stop()
        tb.wait()
    qapp.aboutToQuit.connect(quitting)

    #######################
    ## this is my addition
    ##
    thread = Thread(target = func_to_run, args = (tb, ), daemon=True)
    thread.start()
    ## end my addition
    #######################
    qapp.exec_()
```

Here's how you could use it:

```py
# This is your GRC-generated Python module
from my_generated_FM_receiver import my_generated_FM_receiver


def runMe(tb):
    freqs = [100e6, 101e6]
    for freq in freqs:
        tb.osmosdr_source_0.set_center_freq(freq)

set_up_qt_top_block_and_run_func_in_thread(my_generated_FM_receiver, runMe)
```

P.S.:
In GRC 3.9+, the [Python Snippit](https://wiki.gnuradio.org/index.php/Python_Snippet) may be better.